Esp32 cam qrcode reader continuous rebboting
I m doing a project and need a qrcode reader using an esp32cam, im using an ai-thinker and it gives me always the same error.
`ELF file SHA256: 78411d9208da398c
Rebooting...
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46
rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:1344
load:0x40078000,len:13964
load:0x40080400,len:3600
entry 0x400805f0
setsetcam.Connected to WiFi
ola
ERROR A stack overflow in task loopTask has been detected.
Backtrace: 0x40083959:0x3ffaedf0 0x4008db6d:0x3ffaee10 0x40090fa5:0x3ffaee30 0x4008f723:0x3ffaeeb0 0x4008dc7c:0x3ffaeee0 0x4008dc2c:0x00000000 |<-CORRUPTED
`
i will put here the code i'm using
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h> 
#include <QRCode.h>
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include "quirc.h"

// Camera configuration (pin assignments, etc.) will depend on your specific ESP32-CAM module
// ...
#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22

// 4 for flash led or 33 for normal led
#define LED_GPIO_NUM       4

// Wi-Fi and TCP client setup as before
// ...
// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid = "EletroWIFI";
const char* password = "12345678";

// TCP server details
const char* host = "193.137.172.20";
const uint16_t port = 85;

WiFiClient TCP_Client; // Objecto do tipo TCP 
PubSubClient client(TCP_Client);


// Initialize the camera
void initCamera() {
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sccb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sccb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG; // for streaming
  //config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_RGB565; // for face detection/recognition
  config.grab_mode = CAMERA_GRAB_WHEN_EMPTY;
  config.fb_location = CAMERA_FB_IN_PSRAM;
  config.jpeg_quality = 12;
  config.fb_count = 1;
  // ... (configure your camera settings here)
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }
}

// Decode the QR code using the Quirc library
String decodeQRCode(camera_fb_t *frameBuffer) {
  struct quirc *qrDecoder = quirc_new();
  if (!qrDecoder) {
    Serial.println("Failed to allocate memory for QR decoder");
    return "";
  }

  if (quirc_resize(qrDecoder, frameBuffer->width, frameBuffer->height) < 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to resize QR decoder");
    quirc_destroy(qrDecoder);
    return "";
  }

  uint8_t *image = quirc_begin(qrDecoder, NULL, NULL);
  memcpy(image, frameBuffer->buf, frameBuffer->len);
  quirc_end(qrDecoder);

  int numCodes = quirc_count(qrDecoder);
  Serial.print("Number of QR codes detected: ");
  Serial.println(numCodes);

  for (int i = 0; i < numCodes; i++) {
    struct quirc_code code;
    struct quirc_data data;
    quirc_extract(qrDecoder, i, &code);
    quirc_decode_error_t err = quirc_decode(&code, &data);
    if (err) {
      Serial.print("Failed to decode QR Code: ");
      Serial.println(quirc_strerror(err));
      continue;
    }
    // Assuming only one QR code in the image, return the decoded text
    quirc_destroy(qrDecoder);
    return String((char *)data.payload);
  }

  quirc_destroy(qrDecoder);
  return ""; // No QR code found
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("set");
  initCamera();
  Serial.print("setcam");
  // Wi-Fi connection setup as before
  // ...
  
  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

  client.setServer("193.137.172.20", 85); // O Servidor MQTT, Broker, reside no pc “192.168.1.2”
 // client.setCallback(callback); 
  client.connect("esp32_103268"); // O ESP regista-se no Broker, com o nome “esp8266” 
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("ola");
  delay(2000);
  // Capture a frame
  camera_fb_t *frameBuffer = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if (!frameBuffer) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    return;
  }

  // Decode QR code from the captured frame
  String decodedQR = decodeQRCode(frameBuffer);
  if (decodedQR.length() > 0) {
    Serial.println("Decoded QR Code: " + decodedQR);
    // Send the decoded QR code via TCP as before
    // ...
    if (!client.connected()) {
      Serial.println("Connection to server failed");
      client.connect("esp32_103268"); // O ESP Regista-se no Broker com o nome "esp32_103268"
    }

    client.loop();
    // Send the decoded QR code
    client.publish("qrcode_espcam", decodedQR.c_str());
    Serial.println("Sent QR code to server");
  } else {
    Serial.println("No QR Code found");
  }

  // Return the frame buffer
  esp_camera_fb_return(frameBuffer);
  delay(2000); // Wait for 2 seconds before the next capture
}


if anyone could help it would be apreciated.
i tried using a different library but i could not get it to work. This code was working until mid april this year but now its giving the error above.
